# How do I remove free shipping after discount code has been applied?

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, free-shipping

Having an issue at the moment with free delivery on my site.

It is set that any order over £70 gets Free UK Delivery.

However at the moment we are running a discount code with another client set up. They get 33% discount. Orders that are originally around £85 are being discounted to £56.95 and they are still allowed free delivery at that price. It seems that free delivery uses the subtotal after discount rather than before. Is there a quick fix for this, as it is happening quite a lot.

Actions and conditions images:

[image]

[image]

I have even got the free shipping set to no and its still allowing free shipping.

Im on version 1.9.2, also any advise on weather this rule is setup correctly would be appreciated.

Ive checked out https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-how-to-solve-the-free-shipping-minimum-subtotal-with-discount-issue/ but thats for an older version and dont think that applies anymore.

Comment: Hi, I had a look at the suggested fix. Although the fix is noted for magento 1.7, the code in question as noted by that guide, is still the same. The same fix will apply. I cannot comment on the actual fix, not tried it. no idea if it works. Naturally you don't want to go edit the core files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `collectRates` method of `freeshipping` for this issue.

For this copy `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping.php` in local folder with same directory combination.

and replace this condition ::

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
        $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
)
```

With

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >=
        $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes free shipping model check for the `BaseSubtotalInclTax`.

File: **Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping.php**

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

    $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);

    if (($request->getFreeShipping())
        || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
            $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
    )//here they check for the subtotal
    {
        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $method->setPrice('0.00');
        $method->setCost('0.00');

        $result->append($method);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

You can override this Model and change it to total.

**another way** :

You can play with `salesrule_validator_process` event.

Comment: Cant this be done in the admin panel rather than modifying the code ?

Comment: I dont think from admin panel your query can be achieve. Because you want to apply shipping to total but according to code it applies to subtotal and there is no extra condition for any admin panel action.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is extend out Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address to add "Subtotal with Discount" as a condition options.

See
[shopping cart price rule condition based on final price rather than subtotal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9748/shopping-cart-price-rule-condition-based-on-final-price-rather-than-subtotal)